# running django with lightsail without the terminal

Tags: django, amazon-lightsail

I was able to view my django site in lightsail but using the port 8000 and also having to run the commandline. Is there a way to make this run live without my interaction?

Answer (score 1):

You are running the application on Django built in dev server. This is running on port 8000.  The live site will have to use Apache on port 80 (accessible for http(s))
You need to move your application to Apache on same instance of Lightsail Django.

There is a good tutorial at
https://django.how/resources/django-deployment-aws-lightsail/